# Data loss in Node.js child process

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, object, child-process

I'm trying to send data (as an object) to a child process in Node.js, however, all of my regular expressions get lost in transfer.

```js
var arguments = {
    something: { 
       name: 'test',       
       age: 28,
       active; true          
    },
    otherThing: 'some string',
    regex: /test/i,
    regex2: new RegExp('test')
};

var child = cp.fork(path.join(__dirname, 'child.js'));

child.on('message', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});

child.send(arguments);
```

In the child.js file I have this at the top:

```js
process.on('message', function () {
   console.log(arguments); // This is where the data has changed
});
```

When the log is output from the child process the arguments object instead looks like this:

```js
{
    something: {
        name: 'test',
        age: 28,
        active: true
    },
    otherThing: 'some string',
    regex: {},
    regex2: {}
}
```

So far unable to find anything elsewhere about why this may be happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are completely separate JavaScript processes, you can't send objects. When you pass an object, it gets serialized to JSON and parsed by the child. (See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message).)

JSON does not support serializing regex objects. (Try putting `JSON.stringify(/abc/)` through your console -- you get back `"{}"`.)

To include regexes in a JSON object, you can use the [`json-fn`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-fn) module. It supports serializing functions, dates, and regexes. (It was actually thanks to an issue i raised that they added regex support. :))

You could then do something like:

```
var JSONfn = require('json-fn');
var arguments = {
    something: { 
       name: 'test',       
       age: 28,
       active; true          
    },
    otherThing: 'some string',
    regex: /test/i,
    regex2: new RegExp('test')
};

var child = cp.fork(path.join(__dirname, 'child.js'));
});

child.send(JSONfn.stringify(arguments));
```

and:

```
var JSONfn = require('json-fn');
process.on('message', function (data) {
   console.log(JSONfn.parse(data))); // This is where the data has changed
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks very much, the json-fn library was exactly what i needed. Missed that part of the docs regarding the data being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the regex as a string like

```
myRegex.string = "/test/";
myRegex.modif = "i";
```

Send it to child and then use it like

```
new RegExp(myRegex.string, myRegex.modif);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried json-fn but Date objects stringified are not reverted back to Date. This module [JSON4Process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json4process) stringifies the objects' properties of type Date, RegExp, Function, Set and Map while maintaining the object as a javascript object. You don't need to stringify the whole object if you're using fork, you can directly send it.

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const JSON4Process = require('json4process');

let obj = {
    date: new Date(),
    regex: new RegExp(/regex/g),
    func: () => console.log('func')
}

obj = JSON4Process.stringifyProps(obj);

const child = fork('child.js');
child.send(obj);
```

And then parse the properties back in the other file:

```
process.on('message', data => {
    let obj = JSON4Process.parseProps(data);
});
```

In case you need to use spawn or exec you can just use the default JSON.stringify over the modified object with json4process:

```
let newObj = JSON.stringify(JSON4Process.stringifyProps(obj));
let originalObj = JSON4Process.parseProps(JSON.parse(newObj));
```